# I'm writing my first ever java program and it's not compiling for a certain reason

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

This is the code I have tried running

```
    public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

and it gives me this error:

tempCodeRunnerFile.java:1: error: class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java
public class main

I don't know what's wrong tbh I have tried modifying and it looks similar to me like the example they gave..

Comment: file containing your public class has to be named after that public class name.

Comment: The _file name_ of your `class main` currently is `tempCodeRunnerFile`. The class name of a public class has to be identical to the file name. So either rename the _class_ to `public class tempCodeRunnerFile` (however it should start uppercase due to java naming conventions but that's another topic) or rename the _file_ to `main.java`.

Comment: so i need to save the file as main.java ?

Comment: @AliOsseili Yes, that's what the error message tells you. "[it] _should be declared in a file named main.java_"

Comment: @maloomeister thanks man! how do i upvote u?

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you exactly what is wrong? In the future, you will probably want to do a decent search for [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+error%3A+class+is+public+should+be+declared+in+a+file+named) (please check the link here for an example) and review them before asking. Otherwise, if you ask multiple questions that are considered by the site to be low-quality, you could harm your ability to ask further questions (the site can automatically restrict you), and you will want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the compiler tells you whats wrong. It says, "class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java".
Java has a naming rule, that a class inside a java file needs to match that file name.
Example 1:

Filename -> File.java

inside that file:

```
public class Main{
...
```

does violate that rule (class name does not equal the file name)

Example 2:

Filename -> Main.java

inside that file:

```
public class Main{
...
```

follows that rule (class name does equal the file name)

Also for beginners:
This is a good quick read for basic code / naming conventions.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Answer (score 0):

try naming your file, "main.java"